# What's the required area of a weightless plate in the air, to move only a set distance under given force in given time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics

This discussion got started on [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193311/applying-this-kind-of-physical-magic-to-walk-on-air); see the magical background there. At the root is a problem in pure physics, so I thought I would ask it here too.

It concerns a witch who can walk on air, by manifesting weightless horizontal plates wherever she puts her feet. Those plates have a great surface area, with which they push on the air when the witch rests her weight on them. The air gives way of course (by compressing and by moving out from underneath the plate), but before that the witch can push herself off and gain altitude. Then she dissipates the first plate and manifests another for her second foot, a little above the first one. Repeat a couple thousand times and she's high enough to fly around using a variation on the magic.

I need to narrow down the surface area of these magical plates, to get a size limitation for my magic system.

Here's how far I got. The variables: you have a witch weighing 50 kg, who wants to get herself 20 cm higher (for a single step). That's about 100 Joules against standard Earth gravity, or 333 Watts if done in 0.3 seconds.

Now, the magical plate will drop when she rests on it; but that should be minimised, or stepping gets her nowhere. Let's say that it cannot drop more than 2 cm during those 0.3 seconds, so she still gets 90% of altitude she would if she were walking on an earth staircase. That makes her average upwards velocity 0.6 m/s.

So I need the surface area of the flat plate, so that under a given air pressure and temperature, it will drop only 2 cm in 0.3 seconds when subjected to the downwards force of the witch's weight (490 N) as well as the force of her trying to maintain the velocity against Earth's gravity, which is another 490 N if I understand [the physics](https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravity_work_against_gravity.htm#.X_MgiTSSlPY) correctly. I don't think the air resistance upwards is a great factor here due to the low velocity involved.

So now my question is what equations to use for the plate, and here's where my knowledge, intuition, and Google fu ended. I found the drag equation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation) and could make the drag force *equal* the required 980 N, but that requires extra air pressure, like through flow of air upwards. I am sure the answer is within reach but I just do not know how to proceed.

Comment: If you think that air resistance is not important, why would the area matter?

Comment: @nasu air resistance *upwards*, the air resistance of the witch's own body as she goes up.

Comment: Then why not just use drag equation? The velocity is of the order of cm/s and not 0.6 m/s. I would expect a very large area as the plate is almost at rest.